# @grant GM functions from @require'd script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I'm writing a series of Greasemonkey scripts. Those scripts share most of their features, so I thought useful to extract the common features.

In `common.js` are common features, and they call GM_functions (e.g. `GM.xmlHttpRequest`). Each userscript `@require [...]/common.js`

Is there a way to avoid repeating all the metadata in each `script.user.js` :

```
// @require      [...]/common.js
// @grant        GM.getResourceText
// @grant        GM.xmlHttpRequest
// @grant        GM.setValue
// @grant        GM.getValue
// @connect      localhost
// @resource     styleSheet [...]/style.css
```

?

I tried to `@grant` in `common.js` (or by calling it `common.user.js`), but it seems like Greasemonkey ignores it anyway.

I understand this can be considered a security flaw, because you may not know what privileges you end up granting because of the @require's cascading @grants. However Greasemonkey could logically infer the final privileges from all the @required scripts.

I have the same question for `@resource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unlikely to ever happen.

1. There is very little demand for it.
2. There is even less need for it.
3. It would be a huge security headache:

   1. The various engines already struggle with alerting the user about what evil things a script is trying to do -- and most users ignore it anyway.
   2. Making sure that a previously good `@require`d file didn't break bad.  Most engines and scripts do not even check [subsource integrity](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#Subresource_Integrity) (hash) in the first place.  This would be ten times worse if `@require`s could alter metadata.
   3. Just determining what the final permissions could be would be a challenge.  All of the usercript engines have more important/urgent things to code before that.

I understand the desire to code in a modular and DRY way, but superpowered `@require` files are not the answer.

---

You can probably setup your build environment (EG *Git*) to automatically add `@grant`s for certain `@require`d files when it assembles the final `.user.js` file.

If you don't have such a build/source tracking environment, then you are [courting disaster](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=source%20code%20dependency%20%22disasters%22&ia=web) with superpowered (or any) modules anyway.